# Evaluate the integral of $17 \tan^3(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the Integral:
>   $$\int 17 \tan^3(\theta)$$

I got $$17(\tan^2(\theta)/2 - \ln(\sec(\theta))) + C$$ But it is not right.

Comment: what is right answer, then?

Answer (score 3):

$tan^3x=(tan^2x+1)tanx-tanx$ Now integrate right hand side

Answer (score 1):

We compute the derivative of your answer, getting

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\theta} 17 \left(\frac{\tan^2\theta}{2} - \ln \sec \theta \right)&= 17 \frac{2\tan\theta \sec^2 \theta}{2} - 17 \frac{1}{\sec \theta} \sec{\theta} \tan{\theta} \\
&= 17 \tan\theta \sec^2\theta - 17 \tan \theta
\end{align*}

Now use the fact that $\sec^2{\theta} - 1 = \tan^2{\theta}$.

---

Conclusion: Your answer is equivalent to the correct one.